# Android equivalent for determining time passed

Tags: java, android

In iOS, I'm doing the following to determine how much time has passed in my code:

```
self.timeStart = [NSDate date];
self.timeLapse = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timeStart];
```

How can I do the equivalent in Android returning the same value of self.timeLapse from the above code?

I already tried the following but the values were different:

```
timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
timeLapse = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: **"I already tried the following but the values were different:"** : What do you mean by that? That code should work and give you the absolute difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving my problem by using this:

```
timeStart = System.nanoTime();

timeLapse = System.nanoTime() - timeStart;
timeLapse = (float) (timeLapse / 1000000000.0);
```

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, but are you sure you modified the right code? NSTimeInterval returns seconds and System.currentTimeMillis() returns milliseconds.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns non exact millisecond time, `System.nanoTime()` is used for more specific and exact values. What is your use case that you actually need this extra precision?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk An `NSTimeInterval` is a double containing the whole and partial seconds between two `NSDate` so he is indeed getting roughly the same things.